# Get top 20 elements in Azure, with SQL and Azure API

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, azure, azure-mobile-services

Hej

My SQL skills is very limited, so I would like some help.

I have a table of elements that people can vote for, in an Azure MobileService table. Looking something like:

**TableName**

---

```
                                   ID | Content | Votes |
```

---

From this Table I would like to get the 20 elements with the highest votes. If some have the same votes, It should just choose one of these. The optimal was that I with a GET post to an MobileService API could choose the top votes range, such a new call would get the next twenty elements.

And API in Azure looks like this:

```
    exports.get = function(request, response) { 
        //some code
        response.send();
    }
```

And can be called by

```
    var results = await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<Class>("APIname", System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.PostorGet, DictionaryOfInformationSendToTheAPI);
```

So what I would like is that I send a HttpMethod.Get command, where I send the range I want in the dictionary to the API call. The API call will then respond with getting the information from the table **tableName**, either by returning the ID's or the entire row.

I do not know how so here is just a guess to get the largest but hope somebody can help me create this command, Something like

```
    exports.get = function(request, response) { 
    //Not working so just a guess
        var sqlSpecs = "READ from tableName WHERE votes is" + request.rangeMax + " to " + request.rangemin;
        mssql.query(sqlSpecs, {
         success: function(items)
            {
                console.log("ok");
                response.send(items);
            },
            error: function(err)
            {
                console.log("there was a problem finding the Specified range" + request.rangeMax + " to " + request.rangemin, "" + err);
            }
        });
    }
```

Finally I am of course open of other Ideas of how to access it smarter. Maybe an extra table with top 20 ? But the problem for me is that the infrastructure would be much bigger, and thought therefore the SQL command must be smarter. But please chip in, with Ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {    
    var collectionOfVotes = request.service.tables.getTable('CollctionOfVotes');
    collectionOfVotes.orderByDescending('Votes')
    .read({ success: function(results) { 
        results.forEach(function(r) {
                console.log(r);
            });
    }});
};

or

exports.get = function(request, response) 
{    
    mssql.query('select top 20 * from CollctionOfVotes order by Votes desc', 
    {
      success: function(results) 
      {
            results.forEach(function(r) {
                console.log(r);
            });
      },
      error: function(err) 
      {
                console.log("error is: " + err);
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access your table like this:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {    
    var myTable = request.service.tables.getTable('tableName');
    // Do something with the table here…
};
```

or you can perform a query exactly the way you are doing:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) 
{    
    mssql.query('select top 20 * from tablename', 
    {
      success: function(results) 
      {
         console.log(results);
      },
      error: function(err) 
      {
                console.log("error is: " + err);
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Again Thank you I will try this. I know I can do the first one, but since this will do alot of server computation and costs money in Azure, I am not so interested in that. I thought of having my own computer standing as server taking the table and run it through for the highest, but again seemed stupid :) Do you know in the second one how I can return the results as a list.  And regarding top 20, how does it know which parameter I am searching it for? And finally how would I then search for the next twenty: 'select top 40 to 20 * from tablename' ?

Comment: R: In the second one, the result will be inside "results" variable of success function. Just iterate over it.

Comment: If you don't specify, it will get the first 20 based on Id (Key).

Comment: For the next 20, you must get the id of the last item, and modify your query to get the next 20, where Id > 20thId

Comment: Here some useful links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554212.aspx   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj591477.aspx

Comment: mssql.query('select top 20 * from tablename',. So if I want it to take top 20 from Votes I have to do what?  mssql.query('select top 20 Votes from tablename', or what?

Comment: @JTIM mssql.query('select top 20 * from Votes',

Comment: No, sorry you are misunderstanding. I have a table lets say CollctionOfVotes, in that I have the normal id of inserted item, and then I have Votes, that keeps getting updated.
I then want a script that takes the 20 ones  with the highest votes at that time.
So I need something like 'select top 20 Votes from CollectionOfVotes'